# how do I format a nested if-else statement in python to make it work?

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, nested

I am taking a intro to scripting class and have a prompt to make a program that will accept an input month and then an integer day and tell what season it falls in, or to write 'Invalid' if the input fails to meet the criteria (zybooks lab 3.12.1). I have seen some examples of this, but they wrote this a different way, and I want to learn this, not copy already solved problems. I defined my inputs, made a list of acceptable string inputs to check from, then further broke the list down into months by how many days are in them. I set checks to make sure the input int value falls within the range of the month entered, and set that value to True if it passed the check. Relevant code follows:

```
input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())

months_list = [
    'January', 'February',
    'March', 'April', 'May',
    'June', 'July', 'August',
    'September', 'October',
    'November', 'December']

day30_months = (months_list[3], months_list[5], months_list[8], months_list[10])
day31_months = (months_list[0], months_list[2], months_list[4], months_list[6], months_list[7],
                months_list[9], months_list[11])
day29_months = (months_list[1])

if input_month not in months_list:
    print('Invalid')

if input_month in day30_months and 0 < input_day <= 30:
    input_day = True

if input_month in day31_months and 0 < input_day <= 33:
    input_day = True

if input_month in day29_months and 0 <= input_day <= 29:
    input_day = True

if input_month == 'March':
    if input_day == True:
        if input_day <= 19:
            print('Winter')
        else:
            print('Spring')
    else:
        print('Invalid')

if input_month in ('April', 'May'):
    if input_day == True:
        print('Spring')
    else:
        print('Invalid')
```

So far everything works and I like this route, but my second nested function under 'March' doesn't work. If my input is 'March' and '35', it prints Invalid. If my input is 'March' and '11', it prints Winter. But for some reason if I input 'March' and '22', it prints Winter, and I don't know why it doesn't move on to the else condition after the true check for input_day and a value greater than 20.
Can someone tell me why? I can't find an answer for why this won't fail the input_day <= 19 check and print 'Spring'.
Also, PyCharm tells me that the lines for "if input_day == True" can be simplified, but it doesn't tell me how.
Thanks.

Comment: Minor nit.  You want `<= 33` to be `<= 31`.  But that's not your bug.

Comment: How can input_day be True and smaller or equal to 19 ?? Technically in python this works but it certainly is not what you want. Don't change input_day in your code.

Comment: You're using `input_day` as both an integer and a boolean.  I think you want two separate variables here.

Comment: These things are true...but I don't know how to do what I am trying to do. I want the input number to be checked for validity without writing the full check under each month of the year. I can do it that way if it is correct, but I wanted the check to return a condition, and then later just check the condition? I don't know the proper way to do that.

Comment: You should use `elif` when you have a series of mutually-exclusive conditions. then you can use `else:` at the end if the input doesn't match any of the criteria, and that can display "Invalid"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*But for some reason if I input 'March' and '22', it prints Winter, and I don't know why it doesn't move on to the else condition after the true check for input_day and a value greater than 20. Can someone tell me why?*

The reason for this behavior is that you overwrite the integer value of the `input_day` if it is 22 with the value `True` in your code. In Python `True` is equivalent to `1` (one) so later in the code `1 <= 19` gives `Winter`.

Replace all of the `input_day` with `day_OK` if you check for validity of the day and you will get the expected behavior.

Don't forget to set `day_OK=False` first, then if you check validity set `day_OK=True` and use:

```
if input_month == 'March':
    if day_OK: # means the same as day_OK == True
        if input_day <= 19:
            print('Winter')
        else:
            print('Spring')
    else:
        print('Invalid')
```

But ... best you rewrite your code as suggested by *Barmar* in the comment to your question.

Here how it can look like after such rewrite:

```
input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())

months_list = [
    'January', 'February',
    'March', 'April', 'May',
    'June', 'July', 'August',
    'September', 'October',
    'November', 'December']

day30_months = (months_list[3], months_list[5], months_list[8], months_list[10])
day31_months = (months_list[0], months_list[2], months_list[4], months_list[6], months_list[7],
                months_list[9], months_list[11])
day29_months = (months_list[1])

if input_month not in months_list:
    print('Invalid month', input_month)

day_OK=False

if   input_month in day30_months and 0 < input_day <= 30:
    day_OK = True
elif input_month in day31_months and 0 < input_day <= 31:
    day_OK = True
elif input_month in day29_months and 0 < input_day <= 29:
    day_OK = True
else:
    print('Invalid day for', input_month)
    
if day_OK and input_month == 'March':
    if input_day <= 19:
        print('Winter')
    else:
        print('Spring')

if day_OK and input_month in ('April', 'May'):
    print('Spring')
```

The next step of improvement of your code could be usage of a dictionary for the months and days in a month making the code simpler and shorter:

```
dict_months = {
    'January':31, 'February':29, 'March':31, 'April':30, 'May':31,
    'June':30, 'July':31, 'August':31, 'September':30, 'October':31,
    'November':30, 'December':31
    }
month_OK=False
day_OK=False

input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())

if input_month in dict_months:
    month_OK=True
else:
    print('Invalid month', input_month)
if month_OK and 0 < input_day <= dict_months[input_month]:
    day_OK = True
else:
    print('Invalid day',input_day,'for', input_month)

if day_OK and input_month == 'March':
    if input_day <= 19:
        print('Winter')
    else:
        print('Spring')

if day_OK and input_month in ('April', 'May'):
    print('Spring')
```

---

With dictionary values as tuples listing days of the month and the given month preceding days in the year it would be possible to determine from the user input the day of the year what would cut the following if-conditions to four for the four year seasons:

```
dict_months = {
    'January':(31,0), 'February':(29,31), 'March':(31,60),
    'April':(30,91), 'May':(31,121), 'June':(30,152),
    'July':(31,182), 'August':(31,213), 'September':(30,244),
    'October':(31,274), 'November':(30,305), 'December':(31,335)
    }

month_OK=False
day_OK=False

input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())

if input_month in dict_months:
    month_OK=True
else:
    print('Invalid month', input_month)
    

if month_OK and 0 < input_day <= dict_months[input_month][0]:
    day_OK = True
else:
    print('Invalid day',input_day,'for', input_month)

if day_OK and month_OK:
    day_of_year = dict_months[input_month][1]+input_day 
    if   day_of_year <= 79 or day_of_year >= 356:
        print('Winter')
    if  80 <= day_of_year <= 172:
        print('Spring')
```

Comment: This is what I am trying to do, I just didn't know how to say it. As for Barmar's suggestion, I don't know where he means to write the elif part of it...

Comment: Wow, this really is excellent. I wish some of the textbook examples worked this way...it teaches all the concepts, but then just assumes you can implement it with no further help. There is no example to look at for this one in particular. The dictionary example you gave is exactly what I wanted to do, but didn't now how to assign the values that way, so I made the variable lists that I made. Thanks a bunch, this is super helpful.

Comment: Notice that the second dictionary version demonstrates the huge impact of choice of appropriate data structure on size of the required code.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I can tell you are having trouble with the stuff under the March check and why it thinks 22 is smaller or equal to 19.

Well, that is because you check if the `input_day` variable is smaller or equal to 19, however before checking you also seem to set that to True, a boolean value. The way bools work in Python is that the `False` and `True` keywords are placeholders for the integers `0` and `1` respectively, and seeing as both of those are smaller than 19 your issue surfaces.

Example:

```
var = True
if var <= 1: # This will always trigger since var is technically equal to 1.
    print("Here")
```

The fix would be to use a different variable there.

About PyCharm telling you that the `== True` part can be simplified, that's just because the `if` command works by checking if the condition is True. This means that if your variable is already either True or False, there is no need to check if it is equal to that (even if its more intuitive to do so), but that's really just at best a nitpick and at worst a small waste of time.

Comment: That is what I needed to know. I guess I really don't know how to do what I am trying to do. I was trying to write it without writing a specific line for fail condition under each month. The months of the year aren't going to change, but in other cases that could come up later; so if for instance I added the month 'Neveruary' later on to the list for day30_months it would check it against the same checks I established earlier without having to write all of it out again...It would automatically check the number input against being between 0 and 30.

Comment: That's fine really. When you are starting to learn coding you'll not understand everything all the time, and really it will take a lot of practice before you can easily formulate some logic into a 10 line text file of what one might describe as magic CPU runes. Try to re-write the code from the beginning, taking into account what pitfalls you already found and what you learned.